# Create fresh python venv while local have some package installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

I have some issue about create python venv.

Is there any way to make fresh venv without using Docker.

I already try
`pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y`
but result I got back is

```sh
Not uninstalling rospy at /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /home/micls/PECOM/rpi-playground/.venv 
Can't uninstall 'rospy'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Or using `virtualenv --no-site-packages .venv` and result I got

```sh
virtualenv: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-site-packages
SystemExit: 2
```

Comment: Why not just `rm -rf .venv` and then `python -m venv .venv` ?

Comment: @md2perpe I already do that but it still clone back my local package